# Constructing a CComponent

Tags: php, properties, yii, yii-components

`BranchSalaries` is a class derived from CComponent. It has get/set methods for `month` and `year` properties.

The following code does not work (more specifically, does not initialize `year` and `month` properties):

`new BranchSalaries(array('id'=>'branch_salaries', 'year'=>$year, 'month'=>$month));`

What is the simplest way to make a class which can be initialized passing an array to the constructor?

Correction `BranchSalaries` is derived not directly from CComponent but from CDataProvider.

Comment: Did you give the class a constructor?

Comment: @Jessica: I haven't written any constructor. Can you advise, what should be in the body of the constructor?

Comment: I've added some code as an answer, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function __construct($arr){
   foreach($arr AS $key=>$value){
       $this->$key = $value;
   }
}
```

You need a constructor that can process an array.

Edit: If you need to use the setters: (this assumes the setter is like setId() not setid()

```
function __construct($arr){
   foreach($arr AS $key=>$value){
       $method = "set".ucfirst($key);
       $this->$method($value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To setup class as Yii does, you can use `Yii::createComponent()`, and then there is no need to create cunstomized constructor. I  your case this would be:

```
Yii::createComponent(array(
    'class' => 'BranchSalaries',
    'id'=>'branch_salaries',
    'year'=>$year,
    'month'=>$month
));
```

While it does not look user friendly, it can be used for automatic object creation.

`class` parameter can also be used with path alias:

```
Yii::createComponent(array(
    'class' => 'ext.someExtension.BranchSalaries',
    'id'=>'branch_salaries',
    'year'=>$year,
    'month'=>$month
));
```

Also it set class properties from outside class scope, so getters and setters will be automatically used.